# Webview way avoid Syntax error

Tags: javascript, android, function, syntax, webview

no matter what i do, when ihave to send javascript with some html code i receive a lot of different errors like:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", source:  (1)


"Uncaught SyntaxError: test is not a function", source:  (1) (yes it its -_-)
```

my code:

```
             wv.loadUrl("javascript:setMarcacao(alert('<font size></font>')");
```

any solution?

im already loading the page with the:

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("www.thisdontmatteratall.com", html.toString(), "text/html", Constantes.HTML_ENCODING, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple, was hard to find/think, but its ridiculous simple, because the operator in the html tags <> == & and maybe other elements like " can make the reason very unpredictable, so what i did:

first take the code and Escape using Apache Commons:

eg: `String newHtml = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(oldHtml)` //oldHtml = String too ofc

and now you have to send it to the javascript, BUT you must insert everything btw quotes, BUT again, you cant use the just normal quote and it alone, you need to put \ before, so:

PS: the first quote can be normal, the others no..

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:function(" + JavaScriptArgsSTRING + ");
```

ok, i know im not crazy, thats i just to show where you have to pay attention, now the important part:

after you do the escape in the html, it will be strange like bugged, because will change the operators (dont ask me, i dont know how this things works, but i know that its working now =D)

example, 1 arg to the js function

```
String JavaScriptArgsSTRING = " \""+ newHtml + "\"";

\" will make quotes REAL in the String, like every String s = ""; need

explaining in order:

 " before javascript => start the String args 
 " => stop the string and
 start variable space 
 \" => going to make real quote in the string, thats what the js FUNCION need to see 
 " => you need to stop the String
 start created by \" 
 + => concatenation of the string/html whatever you want to send, ofc html code need Escape

 newHtml => the var 

 + => concatenation 

 " => stop the variable \" => close the function arg inside REAL "
 (again, its what js function want to see)

 " => stop the String start created by the second \"
```

and thats it, if you want to send more args inside the function just copy and paste like:

String JavaScriptArgsSTRING = " *\""+ newHtml + "\"*   ,    *\""+ newHtml + "\"*";

and go on, just add more , and paste... (pay attention, when you paste at the IDE, it auto add more ", so look for that

i lost 2 days looking a way to avoid the Syntax error, and that was the way the worked, at least for me...

sorry bad english(someone will fix it =x) and some stupid explanation(im not REAL developer, but i love to work with that)